# How do I give mobs custom names using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing on iOS, and I need some help with commands. I'm trying to give mobs that I spawn custom names. I have tried the following:

```
/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Dr.Tray"}
```

The error message I got was "Invalid Command Syntax"

If you know the correct way to do this, Please do not hesitate to tell me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only data tags that work in Pocket Edition are `CanPlaceOn` and `CanDestroy` for items. To rename a mob, you have to use an item tag.

Comment: Thank you! Now I ask how do I use canplaceon and candestory?

Comment: Look at the wiki. The comments aren't the place to answer a completely different question.