# Is there a way to spawn mobs with unique names?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm an avid Command Block user for Minecraft: Bedrock Edition and I'm currently diving into a system for a Boss Spawner for what's essentially an RPG-style dungeon with a Boss Spawner and boss at the end. I've spent quite a bit of time trying to piece together a command that can detect when the "boss" entity dies so as to give the player an automatic reward and to teleport them safely from the dungeon.
The only problem is that the command requires the entity that I'm spawning as the boss, which is a skeleton, in this case, to have the unique name "TheMinion". I've been able to create a system that can detect the skeleton entity and apply the correct armor, weapon, and effect combination that I want, but I cannot find one that will apply a `nametag` to the entity.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could share a solution to this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I give mobs custom names using command blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/318245/how-do-i-give-mobs-custom-names-using-command-blocks)

Comment: not really @Corsaka. I've looked into that, but either I'm doing something wrong or there isn't a way to spawn in the mob with a predetermined nametag. Those place and destroy commands only work for placeable blocks or things like levers and buttons, but not nametags. Thank you though.

Comment: In that; there's no command to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I summon a named mob?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374587/how-do-i-summon-a-named-mob)

Answer (score 0):

you could use this command: /summon skeleton "TheMinion" ~ ~ ~

or you could use dispensers with named spawn eggs

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is:
`/summon skeleton ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"\"[Custom Name]\""}`

Comment: Oops! This comment is for Java Edition, but the question is asking for Bedrock Edition.

Answer (score 0):

```
/summon skeleton TheMinion 0 0 0
```

Simply put your nametag in between the entity ID and the spawn position.

or if you need to add a spawn event (such as to making a creeper charged)

```
/summon creeper 0 0 0 minecraft:become_charged TheCreeper
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/summon <entity> <location(xyz)>  <spawn_event>  <custom_name>
```

or simpler:

```
*/summon <mob> <custom_name> <location(xyz)>
```

Notes: 1) if you want to summon it in your location, use ~ ~ ~, and if you are using the second command no need to write it.
2) [See more about spawn events](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_event)

I hope this helps.