# How do I summon a named mob?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Java Edition, I can name a mob by using NBT tags like this:

```
/summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:'{"text":"TheUndead"}'}
```

But in Bedrock Edition, I've heard NBT is not accessible from commands.

What can I do to summon a mob with a custom name tag using the `/summon` command?

---

[Browse more workarounds for getting/setting NBT in Bedrock Edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/250180)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A space for a name is now included in the `/summon` command.

Let's look at the documentation for the command, specifically the syntax.

```
summon <entityType: EntityType> [spawnPos: x y z] [spawnEvent: string] [nameTag: string]
summon <entityType: EntityType> <nameTag: string> [spawnPos: x y z]
```

This allows us to enter a custom entity name directly into the command. The difference between the two versions is for whether you want to use a spawn event or not.

For example, to replicate the JE command in the question:

```
summon zombie CustomZombieNameHere ~ ~ ~
```

If you want to use a spawn event, it would look like this:

```
summon zombie ~ ~ ~ minecraft:as_baby CustomBabyZombieNameHere
```

If your desired custom mob name contains spaces, you must surround the name with quotation marks `"`. If, while doing so, you need to include a quotation mark as *part* of the name, escape them with a backslash `\` before each one.

```
summon zombie "Hello! My name is \"John\"." ~ ~ ~
```