# How can I summon a charged creeper?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Java Edition, you can summon a charged creeper using the `powered` NBT tag:

```
/summon creeper ~ ~ ~ {powered:1b}
```

How can I do this in Bedrock Edition, where there are no NBT tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the `minecraft:become_charged` [spawn event](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_event):

```
/summon creeper ~ ~ ~ minecraft:become_charged
```

If you want to also [give it a custom name](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/374588/188492), put the name after the spawn event:

```
/summon creeper ~ ~ ~ minecraft:become_charged "Charged Creeper"
```

Note: Only one spawn event can be used when summoning a mob, so you cannot use other spawn events such as `minecraft:start_exploding` when summoning charged creepers.